# How to Change OneToOne model Field Default Message in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, model, django-admin

I have suppose following model.

```
class Replied(BaseModel):
    reply = models.OneToOneField(Review, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    show_reply = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    replied_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Reply'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Replies'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

When I tried adding more than reply to certain reply the error message by default given by Django Admin is as follow.
`Reply with this Reply already exists.`
I want certain message like this.

**Reply to this review already exists.**

How can I do that?
In my opinion it should be done in admin so here is my admin.py code

```
@admin.register(Replied)
class RepliedAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'replied_by',
        'created_at')

    list_filter = ('replied_by',)

    list_display_links = ('replied_by',)
```

Comment: Why not change the `reply = ...` to `review = ...`.? This is the reason why you get this message.

Comment: changed my field to `reply_to` got same message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [**`error_messages=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#error-messages) for the `unique` error message:

```
class Replied(BaseModel):
    reply = models.OneToOneField(
        Review,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        error_messages={'unique': 'Reply to this review already exists.'}
    )
    show_reply = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    replied_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Reply'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Replies'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

That being said, the default message is:

```
,code>'unique': '%(model_name)s with this %(field_label)s already exists.'
```

so by setting the [**`verbose_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name), this issue is also resolved, and all other error messages will be adapted:

```
class Replied(BaseModel):
    reply = models.OneToOneField(
        Review,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='review'
    )
    show_reply = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    replied_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Reply'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Replies'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```